# TeeChart package for silverlight 2010

Tags: teechart

Is there any specifc tchart package for Silverlight (vs 2010). ? if so plz provide the necessary details ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is called TeeChart.Silverlight.dll and is included with the TeeChart for .NET 2012 version. A fully functional evaluation version can be downloaded [here](http://www.steema.com/download/net).